# AxiosError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios

I m newbie who is learning to play with API. I m getting POST req error while using axios.

In [docs](https://support.streamsb.com/docs#api-Upload_File-PostHttpsSsuploaderStreamsbComUpload01) of API which I want to interact, they give curl example.

```
curl -X POST https://ssuploader.streamsb.com/upload/01
 -d "api_key=948324jkl3h45h"
 -d "@path/filename.mp4"
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I am trying to make that POST request using axios. I wrote simple script like this.

```
const axiosConfig = {
    headers : { 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
}
const file = __dirname + "/video/Video.mp4";
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(file);
const data = `api_key=${API_KEY}&${fileData}`;

axios.post('https://ssuploader.streamsb.com/upload/01', data, axiosConfig).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data);  
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Getting Error : ", err);
});
```

I am getting this error.

```
Getting Error :  AxiosError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ssuploader.streamsb.com
```

I m really new to interacting with API, so that I thought some of my structure was wrong while converting curl to axios. I really don't know what to do. I mean I can't figure out my false. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

---

**Some Changes**

I figure out some of my false with the help of answers. I forget to GET the server first. So that I updated my code to this.

```
const file = __dirname + "/video/Video.mp4";
const fileData = fs.createReadStream(file);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileData);
formData.append('api_key', API_KEY);
console.log(formData)


axios.get(`https://api.streamsb.com/api/upload/server?key=${API_KEY}`).then(result => {
    const url = result.data.result;
    axios.post(url, formData, axiosConfig)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Getting Error : ", err);
  });

})
```

But I am getting new Error.

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand from the documentation this is 2 step process. At first you need to get the upload URL (server as they call it) and then use it to upload your file.

So use something like this:

```
axios.get(`https://api.streamsb.com/api/upload/server?key=${API_KEY}`).then((result) => {
  const url = result.data.result;
  // your post request to this url here
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Getting Error : ", err);
});
```

Comment: Oh, yea. Thank you so much for pointing me. I didn't GET the server first.

Comment: @TacRevol As I see you are getting 400 error now, but it's hard to say what the issue is. You can check additional info for the error in `err.response.data` key

Answer (score 2):

You are sending fileData as a string in the data Object

1. Use `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`instead of  using `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`
2. Code will be like this

```js
import FormData from 'form-data';

const axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

const file = __dirname + "/video/Video.mp4";
const fileData = fs.createReadStream(file);

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileData);
formData.append('api_key', API_KEY);

axios.post('https://ssuploader.streamsb.com/upload/01', formData, axiosConfig)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Getting Error : ", err);
  });
```

If you have any query, you can ask

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my structure mistake. If I have any query, I will ask in this comment section. I am really appreciate your helps.

Comment: I got this new error => AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: I edited my question with updated code.

Comment: This issue occur from  your endpoint: https://ssuploader.streamsb.com/upload/01

Answer (score 2):

It's them, not you.

There is no DNS record for `ssuploader.streamsb.com` (you can enter it into https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx to check), which means that when you try to connect to it, it leads nowhere.

Unless you do some digging and find a domain from them that has a DNS record, there isn't anything you can do.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me the fact. I am emailed to them about that.

Comment: This is not the URL to use, it is just an example - you first need to get the upload URL as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75085886/3592771)