# How to convert this curl to POST request using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have curl command example. But I wanna make POST request using axios from nodejs. I got this curl example from [docs](https://support.streamsb.com/docs#api-Upload_File-PostHttpsSsuploaderStreamsbComUpload01). Here is curl example.

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/upload
 -d "api_key=API_KEY"
 -d "@path/filename.mp4"
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

There is .mp4 in my project dir.

```
const filePath = __dirname + "/video/Video.mp4";
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(file);
```

I m used readFileSync to get fileData. Is that actually right? If there is something wrong, please point me out. I hope someone can give me example structure of how to make POST req using axios based on this curl example. Thank youu.

Comment: You cannot send binary files over `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Your curl request does not look correct at all

Comment: _"I got this curl example from docs"_... the docs are wrong / bad. The `Curl` example doesn't match the `Form` example. Whoever wrote those docs doesn't know how to use curl

Comment: You were already shown how to do this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75085725/283366) on your other question. FYI an accurate curl example would be `curl -F "api_key=API_KEY" -F "file=@path/filename.mp4" "https://example.com/upload"`

Comment: Yea, But i thought My structure might be still wrong. That's why I want to make sure again.

Answer (score -1):

**Axios Post Structure:**

```
 axios.post(URL, data, config);

const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/json"
};


const data = {
    name: "ABC"
};

const result = await axios.post("https://www.example.com/upload", data, {
    headers: headers
});
```

So in your scenario. try this.

```
//import these
const Formdata = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = __dirname + "/video/Video.mp4";
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(file);

//initialize the form data like this
const dataa = new Formdata();

//now append the form data

dataa.append('file',fileData);

//now for sending the file in the call we use **multipart/form-data**

//let's create headers here

const headerss = {
    headers: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

//All done it's time to post the data to the given URL

axios.post('https://example.com/upload',dataa, headerss).then((res)=> console.log(res));
```

Comment: There's several syntax errors in this answer, the request headers are incomplete and there's no need to read the entire file into memory when you can stream it

Comment: @Phil yea sir, I understand my answer maybe has syntax errors but I think my answer will help him maybe. xD and you are right there is no need to read the all files into the mem.